# can kubuntu and edubuntu desktop both be installed?

Tags: edubuntu

well, the title says it all...

I´ve heard of edubuntu desktop, and I think it´ll be very usefull for my child, so the point is can both desktops live together?

thanks in advance

Comment: Theoretically yes!  No idea as to how you switch between them.

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get install --install-recommends kubuntu-desktop edubuntu-desktop`

Comment: well, obviously I want to switch between them.

Comment: See @IvanTemchenko 's answer

Answer (score 1):

If you can install it like @Daniel
 recommends, "Try

```
sudo apt-get install --install-recommends kubuntu-desktop edubuntu-desktop
```

Then it should be available to be selected on your login screen where you can choose between Kubuntu and Edubuntu; by selecting the wheel next to the password box.

Comment: http://www.howtogeek.com/193129/how-to-install-and-use-another-desktop-environment-on-linux/

Comment: I would recommend including the command to install the two DEs, but aside from that, your answer is good. ;)